# setup func can't change backgroundColor in a viewController

Tags: ios, swift, viewdidappear, ios-lifecycle

I actually use this to switch from a ViewController to another

```
    let vue = MAINSTORYBOARD.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "addhoraire") as! Addhoraire
    self.present(vue, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

sometimes I want to change something before show the view to user so in the VC with will be present I do a `func`. like that

```
// header and cercle.exemple are outlets of a UIView
    public func setup(selectedDay : String){
        loadViewIfNeeded()
        self.selectedDay = selectedDay
        print("jour selectionné : " + self.selectedDay)
        self.header.backgroundColor = UIColor.brown
        self.profTextField.backgroundColor = UIColor.yellow
        self.cercleExemple.backgroundColor = UIColor.yellow
    }
```

And when I want to switch now I do :

```
    let vue = MAINSTORYBOARD.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "addhoraire") as! Addhoraire
    vue.setup(selectedDay: selectedDayinHoraire)
    self.present(vue, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

So it will switch the new VC and execute setup like I want, ,textfield color is changed, cercleExemple too but header will not. `view.backgroundColor`, same problem ... but if I do in the same place header.isHidden = true it work. So it just refuse to change color

header and view bgcolor only change in `ViewDidAppear`. I don't understand why. It's been a week since I've been on this bug, it make me crazy ...

Comment: I looked at your project, but it is really hard to follow what is going on. What I could determine was that the header's color is changing between `viewWillAppear` and `viewDidAppear`, but I am not sure why.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the issue, but I have no idea of the root cause. This seems like it might be an `Apple` bug. The issue is occurring because in Storyboard you are setting the header's background color using a color from the `Assets.xcassets` catalog (`LightSideMenu`). If instead of choosing a color from the `Assets.xcassets` you manually set the background color of the header using the `RGB` sliders or by entering the hex value `#2A6D9E`, then your header's background color will **not** be overridden. Also, make sure you are not resetting it elsewhere like in `viewWillAppear` or `viewDidAppear` as these will be called after your `func setup(selectedDay : String)` method.

[image]

Comment: Perhaps if you update your question with the entire implementation of the view controller where you have `public func setup(selectedDay : String)` we might be able to offer assistance.

Comment: Found it, I am going to need a minute or so to look at your code.

Comment: Dennis's solution work thx ! Do you think that's a Xcode bug or just badly thought feature ?

Comment: @CédricLoneux I feel like its a bug. I have never seen something like that before, but I have also not used the assets catalog to store the apps colors either.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to setup a view before it has loaded, save the information you need to set in a variable and set in `setup`, and when `viewDidLoad` gets called, set the information from those variables.

Comment: why outlets work for other views and textfield and not for these ? That's discursive. 

You want me to in viewDid load {
var headerVar = header
}

and use headerVar in setup ?

Answer (score 0):

As Adrian mentioned, you'll need to wait until the view loads before making changes to it. Have you tried overriding `viewDidLoad()` in your view controller?

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    // Do stuff here
    self.header.backgroundColor = UIColor.brown
    // ...additional view configuration
}
```

If you can't do this in `viewDidLoad()`, you could also try making your UI changes in the `viewWillAppear()` method, instead of waiting until `viewDidAppear()`.

Comment: Like I said in my topic, viewDidLoad and viewWillAppear don’t work, only viewDidAppear work